# Как вернуть открытые вкладки которые были в проекте!

Tags: android-studio

Ситуация такая перед тем как я обновил android studio на 3.6.1
У меня были проекты в них были открытые вкладки когда я открывал такой проект из Backup  я видел вкладки в которых работал.И так было всегда.После последней обновы открывается проект и вкладок нет.
Как вернуть удобство? что конкретно может нужно включить?

Comment: о каких вкладках идет речь? какие-то открытые классы и разметки?

Comment: Да,именно они..

Comment: может поможет ctrl+e

Comment: что-то не то...

Comment: а в чем проблема открыть вкладки снова? у вас же их не 100 штук было открыто?

Comment: я работаю в разное время-и могу не помнить что я делал в данном проекте

Comment: `File > Settings > Editor > General > Editor Tabs > When closing active editor > Activate most recently opened tab` попробуйте такой способ

Answer (score -1):

CTRL + E
Open recent files
Tested on dolphin

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! 1. переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык. 2. пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]